# How can i get the magnitude response on matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, response, magnitude

I am working on a Matlab code ,if this is the code i got so far can someone tell me how can i find the magnitude response of x(t) please.

```
Ac = 1;% Carrier amplitude
wc=0.8*pi; % Carrier frequency
w0= 0.1*pi; % Modulation frequency
Mf = 0.5; % Modulation factor

t=0:0.1:200-0.1;
xt = Ac* (1+ (Mf*cos(w0*t))) .* cos(wc*t);

subplot(4,1,1);
plot(t,xt);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('x(t)');

Xabs=abs(fftshift(fft(xt,2000)))/2000;
w=10*[-1000:999]*2*pi/2000;
subplot(4,1,2);
stem(w,Xabs);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('x[n]');
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are talking about the frequency domain? Would you know how to do it on paper? Share your thoughts!

Comment: The magnitude response assuming frequency domain is the variable `Xabs` in your code. As such, I have no idea what it is you're trying to ask when your code is already computing it.